# syntax error in expression; error token is

Tags: bash, shell, syntax-error

Have the following simple condition, but it fails

```
    now=$(date +"%T")
    echo $now # Just for debugging. Showing correct time
    if (( $"now" >= "11:50:00" && "$now" <= "11:55:00" ))
    then
        do_something
        break
    fi
```

However, I am getting this error
Seems like the hour is cut?! Not 100% sure what the issue is.
./test.sh: line 17: ((: 12:13:04 >= 11:50:00 : syntax error in expression (error token is ":13:04 >= 11:50:00 ")

Cheers!

Comment: `(( ))` starts and ends a math context. Every value inside it needs to be numeric.

Comment: If you want string comparisons, use `[[ ]]` instead.

Comment: And you want `"$now"`, not `$"now"`. The latter is syntax for a translation table lookup.

Comment: thanx all. this was enlightening!